# How to open a url in the browser using AS3 on a standalone flash projector?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, projector, navigatetourl

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://google.com");
navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
```

This works fine on web based swfs, it fails on flash player. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

locally played swfs are in different sandbox that forbids opening outsides urls.
You can make it work if you export it as .exe or try Air.
If you just want to test your swfs locally you can add a 'trusted' directory here http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Comment: i have created a projector both on mac and pc (exe), but it doesnt seem to open a browser on clicking external urls? is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: later tests showed that it works on windows, but fails on mac.